# hostname and /etc/hosts

Tags: hostname

On a server I have had issues with sudo saying

```
sudo: unable to resolve host
```

Now I don't know if this is related but someone else has modified

```
/etc/hostname
```

but not

```
/etc/hosts
```

so that the new hostname is not in it anymore. Having rebooted the machine sudo is working again. Is changing /etc/hostname without modifying /etc/hosts going to cause me problems?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer that works on my (Debian) systems is to add a line to `/etc/hosts`.

From your shell, confirm these results match:

```
$ cat /etc/hostname
somehostname

--- and...---

$ hostname
somehostname
```

`/etc/hosts` functions as a sort of "local dns" by holding the loopback and localhost addresses for IPv4 & IPv6. But it seems that your `/etc/hosts` file may be missing an entry; we'll add it as follows:

Using your favorite editor, e.g. `nano`:

```bsh
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Add the following line to the end of the file:

```
127.0.1.1   somehostname
```

Where `somehostname` matches the contents of `/etc/hostname` as above.

Save the file, exit, reboot & `sudo` should quit complaining. If something/someone is changing your `/etc/hostname` file, you'll need to take other measures to deal with that. See `man hostname` for ideas.

For some background on why this is, see [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=127.0.0.1+vs+127.0.1.1&atb=v297-1&ia=web)

Also note that this was tested in a *private* local network - it may not work if your host has a public IP address and a DNS-hosted FQDN.